# How to debug a case where R CMD check fails under narrow circumstances

Tags: r, package

Apologies for yet another package build debugging, but I'm completely stumped here.

Using `R-devel.sh CMD check taRifx.geo_1.0.6.tar.gz --as-cran` on (X)Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, installed via [this script](http://www.personal.psu.edu/mar36/blogs/the_ubuntu_r_blog/2012/08/installing-the-development-version-of-r-on-ubuntu-alongside-the-current-version-of-r.html), I get the following error:

```
* checking examples ... ERROR
Running examples in ‘taRifx.geo-Ex.R’ failed
The error occurred in:
[ ...SNIP... ]
> ### * </HEADER>
> library('taRifx.geo')
Loading required package: sp
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘lattice’
Error: package ‘sp’ could not be loaded
Execution halted
```

The manual for [package checking](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Package-Dependencies) says:

> Before using these tools, please check that your package can be
>   installed (which checked it can be loaded). R CMD check will inter
>   alia do this, but you may get more detailed error messages doing the
>   install directly.

But when I do that (being sure to use R-devel, loaded with `--vanilla`), I get no error:

```
# 1) 
install.packages("taRifx.geo_1.0.6.tar.gz",repos=NULL)
# 2) 
library(taRifx.geo)
# 3) Profit.
```

If I run `R CMD check` through RStudio or command line R (but not the -devel version), I also get no error.

Thing is, when I search the entire project's code for "lattice", I can't find any case where I use it, even in the example files.  `lattice` is installed and I've tried checking with lattice in `Suggests` and without.

Project code here: https://github.com/gsk3/taRifx.geo

The check logs are [here](http://www.abfriedman.com/misc/temp/taRifx.geo.Rcheck.zip).

Now for the question: How do I go about debugging this?  I have some thoughts as to where the problem might lie (Depends rather than Imports for a few packages, and the spatial packages tend to have very intertangled namespaces), but I can't really begin to solve it unless I can reproduce the error in an environment other than `R CMD check` run from the command line via `R-devel.sh`.

This, by the way, is `Under development (unstable) (2014-05-26 r65771) -- "Unsuffered Consequences"`.  Appropriately named.

**Edit**

Here are the contents of `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library`:

```
akima       digest      labeling  plyr          RJSONIO      stringr
bitops      evaluate    lattice   proto         R.methodsS3  survival
boot        fields      mapproj   pspline       R.oo         taRifx
caTools     functional  maps      RandomFields  RSQLite      taRifx.geo
cluster     gdata       maptools  RColorBrewer  R.utils      testthat
colorspace  geoR        MASS      Rcpp          scales       whisker
data.table  ggplot2     Matrix    RCurl         shapefiles   xtable
DBI         gtable      memoise   reshape2      sp
devtools    gtools      munsell   rgdal         spam
dichromat   httr        nlme      rgeos         splancs
```

The `lattice` description file says:

```
Depends: R (>= 2.15.1)
Built: R 3.2.0; x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu; 2014-05-29 17:14:03 UTC; unix
```

Still the same error on the `CMD check`.

Comment: The checking run alters `.libPaths()`.  Make sure you have req'ed libraries in a place that is always included -- I like `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library` for that.

Comment: I bet you have a package library for released R and that is different from the one that your `R-devel` is using. This is a common issue when trying to use `R-released` and `R-devel` with different, custom package libraries. I had a terrible time getting `R-devel` to find the correct library and gave up and just installed into the respect default library locations., which is fine for package development.

Comment: Thanks both of you.  I'll try installing to `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library` and see how it goes.

Comment: Did you configure R-devel using `--with-recommended`? For me this all works if I compiled with the recommended and use the standard library location `/path-to-build-dir/library` or the equivalent if you installed it.

Comment: I installed it using [these instructions](https://getpocket.com/a/read/321913409) and @DirkEddelbuettel's script.  Will try with `--with-recommended`.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman well that's the default, most often you see `--without-recommended`, esp on `R-devel` installations. The point is, if you followed instructions to not compile with the recommended packages then the locations that `R-devel` will look for packages `BUILD_DIR/library/` (or `INST_DIR/library/` if you installed) won't contain **lattice** and hence the error. This happens because running `R-devel CMD check` doesn't access the same user/site configuration files that running plain 'ol `R-devel` would.

Comment: Checking the script, it was installed `--without-recommended`.  Seems like the easiest thing to do at this point would be to install to the directory that `R-devel.sh CMD check` will look, but from @DirkEddelbuettel's comment that should be `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library`, and the libraries are, indeed, there....

Comment: It's more complicated, what I do at home is different, and I don't have time **right now** to walk you through. You have not even stated what OS and version this is ...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel it's (X)Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, but you should not feel compelled to be my personal help line, and certainly not on an instantaneous basis!  Going to plunk around some more and see what happens.

Comment: My R-devel inst is minimal, and I use recommended packages from either `/usr/lib/R/library` via the `r-cran-*` packages, or the usual path in `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library`. As R-devel is by construction newer, it can always use the packages I use with R-release anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had been attempting to install to the site-wide library at `"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"` which did not solve it, but I instead brute-forced a solution.

First, find all the places R might look:

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"       
[2] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"             
[3] "/usr/lib/R/library"                  
[4] "/usr/local/lib/R-devel/lib/R/library"
```

Then, as root, install to each of those in turn until the error goes away.  As it turns out, it's `"/usr/local/lib/R-devel/lib/R/library"`:

```
install.packages(c('lattice','sp'),lib="/usr/local/lib/R-devel/lib/R/library")
```

Then `q()` that `R-devel` session and run `R-devel.sh CMD check mypackage.tar.gz --as-cran`.

As for why it needs `lattice` in the first place, I suspect it's pulling in an `.Rdata` file at launch which has `lattice` in the namespace.

Many thanks to @DirkEddelbuettel and @GavinSimpson for the various shoves in the right direction.